# Ensure a positive integer number in input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

I have an HTML input element for positive integer numbers. I need to evaluate this input field and ensure that only proper values are inserted.

```js
function exampleFunction(event, element) {

  // If event is not backspace and Not a Number
  if (event.which != 8) {

    //If the event is Not a Number
    if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))) {

      // Cancels the event
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    //If the length reached the limit
    else {

      var value = document.getElementById(element.id).value;
      var maxLength = document.getElementById(element.id).maxLength;
      var valueLength = document.getElementById(element.id).value.length;

      if (valueLength >= maxLength) {

        // Cancels the event
        event.preventDefault();
      } else {

        // Convert the value to a number and back to string. This means leading 0 will be gone.
        document.getElementById(element.id).value = Number(value);
      }
    }
  }

};
```

```html
<input id="exampleInput" type="number" value="0" min="0" step="1" maxlength="5" onkeypress="exampleFunction(event, this)">
```

**purposes**:

- default value is 0
- only numbers shall be accepted

  - no decimal value `.,`
  - no other characters `+-e`
- the input can come from:

  - typing
  - copy
- backspace and delete can also modify the value
- length of input shall also be limited for 5 character length
- leading 0 shall be eliminated after a proper new value

**Problems:**

- the default value is 0 and leading zeros are not immediately deleted, only after the second number is typed
- with ctrl+v `.,+-e` characters can be inserted

**Question:**
Is any better solution for my purposes?
If it is jQuery related, it is also acceptable.

Maybe I am not using the proper event. I tried also to handle the
`input` event but it is not possible to evaluate the input text.
I am not sure if I make this too complicated, or the solution would be much more complex than I think.

Comment: Use `input` event and parse the `value`. Note there is no need to do `getElementById()` since you are already passing in the `element`. For example:  `var value = element.value` or `element.value = Number(value)`

Comment: reshape the value?

Comment: @charlietfl If I use the input, I cannot roll back changes: the event.preventDefault() is not working. These attributes seems also undefined: event.keykode, event.which. As I see, I only can get the actual value of the textbox. That's the reason, why I couldn't accomplish all of the purposes. Do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `.addEventListener()` instead of the inline event handler.

So to the same `input` element, you can add more than one event. To do what you wish to do, there are three events implied:

- `keydown` to prevent the not allowed keys
- `contextmenu` for mouse pasting
- `input` to parseInt the value

The below snippet is restricting the input to nubers only. No dot, minus sign, `e` or whatever except numbers are allowed.

Pasting can be done via [CTRL]+[v] or the mouse `contextmenu`. In both cases, I assume the previous value of the `input` should be squarely cleared.

I took the pasted negative numbers case in account using [Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs).

```js
// Get the element
let myInput = document.querySelector("#exampleInput")

// This event handler only allows numbers, backspace and [ctrl]+[v]
myInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {

  console.log("Key:", event.key)

  // If this is to be a keyboard paste [CTRL]+[v],
  // squarely clears the input value before the paste is done
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "v") {
    console.log("keyboard paste")
    this.value = ""
    return;
  }

  // If the key is not backspace, but is NAN, it is not a number.
  // In short, only a number OR a backspace is allowed at this point.
  if (event.key !== "Backspace" && isNaN(event.key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(" --------- Event prevented")
  }

});

// This handler is for "mouse pastes"
// It squarely clears the input value before the paste is done
myInput.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event) {
  this.value = ""
})

// This handler fixes the value length and parses as a positive integer
myInput.addEventListener("input", function(event) {

  console.log("Original value", this.value)

  // Get the maxlength attribute value
  var maxLength = parseInt(this.maxLength)

  // ParseInt the value (will remove any leading zero) and ensure it is positive
  // Then keep just the [maxlength] first characters.
  var value = Math.abs(parseInt(this.value)).toString().slice(0, maxLength)
  console.log("Fixed value", value)
  this.value = value;
});
```

```html
<input id="exampleInput" type="number" value="0" min="0" step="1" maxlength="5">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go with a *JQuery* solution

**Features**:

- Remove default "0" on focus.
- Set maximum length to (5)
- Allowed numeric content only and <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, <kbd>Arrow-Left</kbd>, <kbd>Arrow-Right</kbd>,
  <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl+a</kbd> buttons.
- Check if the copied text contains any numeric value and collect it and remove non-numeric values.
- Check if pasted text length + current value length are meeting maximum length

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Remove default "0" ONLY! when focus at the input.
  $("#exampleInput").on('focus', function() {
    var oldval = $("#exampleInput").val();
    if (oldval < 1) {
      $("#exampleInput").val("");
    }
  });
  /* SET CTRL+V , CTRL+C funciton */

  var ctrlprs = false,
    ctrlk = 17,
    mccmd = 91,
    vk = 86,
    ak = 65,
    ck = 67;
    
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlk || e.keyCode == mccmd) ctrlprs = true;
  }).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlk || e.keyCode == mccmd) ctrlprs = false;
  });

  //Listen to the input in keydown

  $("#exampleInput").on('keydown', function(e) {
    var txt = $("#exampleInput").val();
    //exceptions for [b-space,end,home,left,right,del]
    var keys = [8, 35, 36, 37, 39, 46];
    var rgx = $.inArray(e.which, keys) < 0;
    var cnvrt = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
/* allow CTRL + "a or c or v" */
 if (ctrlprs && ((e.keyCode == ck) || (e.keyCode == ak) || (e.keyCode == vk))) {
 
    } else if ((txt.length == 5) || (cnvrt.match(/[^0-9]/)) || (e.shiftKey)) {
      if ((rgx)) {
        e.preventDefault();
            /* prevent all text except numbers, and set max input value length to (5) */
      }
    } 
  });

  /*Bind a paste function to check if clipboard data met with requirements or not.*/
  $("#exampleInput").on('paste', function(e) {
    var oldl = $("#exampleInput").val();
    var oldval = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    if (oldval.match(/[0-9]{1,5}$\d/g)) {} else {
      //remove all non-numeric text from clipboard text.
      var newvar = oldval.replace(/\D/g, "");
      setTimeout(function() {
        //check if ( clipboard[Numeric only] + input value ) length equals or less than (5). 
        var totlen = oldl.length + newvar.length;
        if (newvar.length > 0 && totlen <= 5) {
          $("#exampleInput").val(oldl + newvar);
        } else {
          //if total length is more than (5) keep the input value before paste.
          console.log("total length is : " totlen);
          $("#exampleInput").val(oldl);
        }
      }, 1);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="exampleInput" type="number" value="0" min="0" step="1" maxlength="5">
```